# Why is PHP / Materialize Web Site Not Rendering on Server while rendering perfectly Locally?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, materialize

This is an interdisciplinary question overlapping several technologies, languages, and fields of expertise.

I have a web site that I am putting up for a client (an author) for his books and academic research.

Over the past couple of years I have developed a basic template using Google's Materialize CSS (i.e. HTML5 / CSS / Javascript) framework, using their parallax effect with some background images, and then sliced this code up to be within PHP includes in order separate components and make development easier.  It has worked fine (including the two issues that I detail below) as a template for other web sites, including two other web sites for the same author:

[DanielAzariah.com](http://DanielAzariah.com)

[YosefTheStoryOfJoseph.com](http://YosefTheStoryOfJoseph.com)

For each web site, I simply copy and paste these folders with PHP web site files, and then I change the info for each new web site that I develop and put up - and with this basic template I can get web sites up very fast, and then develop custom components to integrate upon request.

For my author Client's web sites for his books, I have put up a web site at each of the two following URLs, and they render fine locally on my PHP 7.1 development server, but when I upload to the same servers hosting the other sites, they are not rendered properly.  Specifically the parallax background images do not show up in the following two URLs, and also the Side Navigation Bar (visible when screensize drops to ipad or smartphones screens) has problems rendering on the internet URL, but renders fine locally.

[BookOfGenesis.org](http://BookOfGenesis.org)

[TheBookOfGenesis.net](http://TheBookOfGenesis.net)

The error messages I get when trying to access the Side Navigator Bar are the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token materialize.js:1988 

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidenav is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (init.js:4)
    at j (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.I (jquery-2.1.1.min.js:2)
```

I have tried validating the HTML at the following URL, but found nothing that is affecting these two specific issues:

https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=http%3A%2F%2Fbookofgenesis.org

I have been coding and developing web sites since 1997, and I really don't understand logically what could be causing these errors to show up only on the internet servers, but the same code renders fine locally.

Any ideas?

**EDIT - MORE INFO REQUESTED IN COMMENTS/RESPONSES **

```
<?php /* <!--  BEGIN SCRIPTS --> */  ?>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".dropdown-trigger").dropdown();
      $('.sidenav').sidenav();
      $('.modal').modal();
    });
</script>
<?php /* <!--  END SCRIPTS --> */  ?>
```

Comment: Which version of materialize are you using , if you're using older version of materialize then it's important you include jquery, if it's newer then there is new syntax, the two don't mix together

Comment: I added code that answers your question and addresses your concerns:  I use Jquery and I use a local copy of the Materialize CSS:
Materialize v1.0.0-rc.1 (http://materializecss.com)

Comment: The issue is that locally all works fine, but on the internet server, the two issues don't render properly.  I would hate to have to start from scratch and recopy one of the first two web sites for this author and recode things...

Comment: Check the order of your scripts, also I see a href tag that is loading scripts?

Comment: Have you checked that all the script files are present and correct, and are loading into the page properly? Does the network tab show that any of them failed?

Comment: @ADyson Yes, all script files are present and correct.  I have simply uploaded the web site folder including all images, css files, scripts, etc. AS-IS from my local machine to my web servers that run PHP files.  There is no change in code.  It simply works locally, but not on the servers.

Comment: @Ainz-sama Where do you see an href tag loading scripts?

Comment: @JerusalemProgrammer have you actually checked the network tab while your page is loading though, to check that all the script files get loaded into the page successfully? Even if you added them to the web site folder it doesn't 100% guarantee they will work in the page - you can have permission problems for example.

Comment: @ADyson It's not just the scripts, but also the background parallax images are not loading.  I went to the Networking tab you mentioned, but don't see any messages or how this can help me.  However, I do see the name of the scripts there, so I reckon they have loaded okay.  Strangely, without my changing anything, the web site BookOfGenesis.org now renders okay for both the side navigation bar script + the background parallax images. Unfortunately, the other web site TheBookOfGenesis.net is still not rendering the images or the script.  So I don't know what can be issue that fixes itself(?)

Comment: im getting a `Unexpected end of file` error in chrome devtools, update your materialize js file from here: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Dogfalo/materialize/v1-dev/dist/js/materialize.js

Comment: `, I do see the name of the scripts there, so I reckon they have loaded okay. `...that depends on the status code next to them. If they show 200 then they succeeded. Anything else such as 403 or 404 probably indicates a problem.